# Looping through values in dict

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How do I loop trough key-value pairs from a dictionary and get the values for each item? I came up with this but i keep getting errors...

`defp processValues (ticket) do
    IO.inspect ticket.value # this doesnt work
end`

`Repo.all(Ticket) #get all tickets 
      |> Enum.group_by(&(&1.aggregate_id)) # group by id
      |> Dict.to_list # maybe not needed?
      |> Enum.map(&(processValues(&1))) # return processed tickets`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify a mapping function that is already defined in a module, you need to use syntax `&ModuleName.function_name/arity`.  In your case, it will be `&processValues/1`.

Here is a simplified example to demonstrate the concept:

```
list  = [%{aggregate_id: 1, value: "test"}, %{aggregate_id: 2, value: "test2"}]

defmodule T do
    defp processValues(ticket) do
        IO.inspect ticket.value
    end

    def process_list(list) do
        list |> Enum.map(&processValues/1)
    end
end

T.process_list list
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this documentation](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html). I would specifically call your attention to this part of the documentation:

```
iex> for {key, val} <- %{"a" => 1, "b" => 2}, into: %{}, do: {key, val * val}
%{"a" => 1, "b" => 4}
```

You'd want something akin to

```
for {key, value} <- ticket, do: process_values(value) # Note snake case.
```

Also note that upper case "T" is wrong. It needs to be lower case "t".  I mean in your example it should be `Repo.all(ticket)` not `Repo.all(Ticket)`
But honestly it's a little hard to tell what you're trying to do. If you have a more specific question, please edit and we'll see if we can give you a more specific answer.